# Failed to load libGLESv2.so.2: libGLESv2.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: chrome, opengl, yocto

Created my own Yocto Linux distribution for **Raspberry Pi 2** (See [Embarcados Tutorial HERE](http://www.embarcados.com.br/raspberry-pi-2-qt5-yocto-parte-1/)), added [`meta-browser`](http://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/branch/master/layer/meta-browser/) + `chromium` recipe. The image built works great and I can run **Chromium** BUT ...

... when I do, I am getting the following Error messages, although the application pops up.

```
raspberrypi2:~$ /usr/bin/chromium/chrome --enable-logging --v=1 --no-sandbox 
[1796:1796:0625/011716:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(164)] Running without the SUID sandbox! See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxSUIDSandboxDevelopment for more information on developing with the sandbox on.
[1819:1819:0625/011717:ERROR:gl_implementation_osmesa.cc(22)] Failed to load libGL.so.1: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[1819:1819:0625/011717:ERROR:gpu_child_thread.cc(145)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
[1831:1831:0625/011717:ERROR:renderer_main.cc(211)] Running without renderer sandbox
[1837:1837:0625/011717:ERROR:renderer_main.cc(211)] Running without renderer sandbox
```

When looking for the `libGL` library, I am getting this

```
root@raspberrypi2:/usr/lib/chromium# find / -name libGL*
/usr/lib/libGLESv2.so
/usr/lib/libGLESv1_CM.so
```

### --use-gl=egl

```
raspberrypi2:~$ /usr/bin/chromium/chrome --enable-logging --v=1 --no-sandbox --use-gl=egl 
[1857:1857:0625/011725:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(164)] Running without the SUID sandbox! See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxSUIDSandboxDevelopment for more information on developing with the sandbox on.
[1880:1880:0625/011725:ERROR:gl_implementation_osmesa.cc(22)] Failed to load libGLESv2.so.2: libGLESv2.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[1880:1880:0625/011725:ERROR:gpu_child_thread.cc(145)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
[1892:1892:0625/011726:ERROR:renderer_main.cc(211)] Running without renderer sandbox
[1897:1897:0625/011726:ERROR:renderer_main.cc(211)] Running without renderer sandbox
```

This time the library is well present in the `/usr/lib` folder.

I tried `ldconfig -v` to no avail

I am guessing it's missing a symbolic link, but I wouldn't know where to. Any pointers?